# Inner joining two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a rather basic question for pandas, but I've tried merge and join to no success
-edit: these are in the same dataframe, and that wasn't clear. We are indeed condensing the data.

```
         print df

       product_code_shipped    quantity  product_code
     0   A12395                   1        A12395 
     1   H53456                   4        D78997
     2   A13456                   3        E78997
     3   A12372                   8        A13456 
     4   E28997                   1        D83126
     5   B78997                   2        C64516
     6   C78117                   9        B78497
     7   B78227                   1        H53456
     8   B78497                   2        J12372
```

So I want to just have one product code column with the unique product codes and their other data. So quantity, and color say, I just want the product codes of the shipped products (and in another column there is color). How do I do this inside the same dataframe?
So I should get 
                print df2

```
       product_code_shipped    quantity  product_code   color 
     0   A12395                   1        A12395        red
     1   H53456                   4        H53456        blue
     2   B78497                   2        B78497        yellow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, specifically where "*unique* product codes" enter in...are we condensing the data? The example does not make that clear. Nonetheless I'll give it a shot:

Many DataFrame methods rely on the indexes to automatically align data. In your case, it seems convenient to set the index of these DataFrames to the product code. So you'd have this:

```
In [132]: shipped
Out[132]: 
                      quantity
product_code_shipped          
A                            1
B                            4
C                            2

In [133]: info
Out[133]: 
               color
product_code        
A                red
B               blue
C             yellow
```

Now, `join` requires no extra parameters; it gives you exactly what (I think) you want.

```
In [134]: info.join(shipped)
Out[134]: 
               color  quantity
product_code                  
A                red         1
B               blue         4
C             yellow         2
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify it by giving example input *including where `color` comes from* and the exact output that would come from that input.